# Is there a better way to find a specific value in dynamic query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, dynamic

I'm trying to find out is there a value in a dynamic query, at the moment I'm using this solution:

```
DECLARE 
  @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
, @ISLN NUMERIC(9,0) = '967272'
SET @SQL = 
'SELECT * 
FROM ITEM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SHIPMENT_DETAIL 
ON ITEM.ITEM = SHIPMENT_DETAIL.ITEM 
AND (SHIPMENT_DETAIL.COMPANY = ITEM.COMPANY OR ITEM.COMPANY IS NULL)  
WHERE (SHIPMENT_DETAIL.warehouse = N''SH'' ) 
ORDER BY ITEM.ITEM  ASC'
SELECT @SQL = STUFF (
    @SQL
    , 8
    , 1
    , 'INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_LINE_NUM'
)
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (ISLN NUMERIC(9,0))
INSERT INTO @TEMP (ISLN)
EXEC SP_SQLEXEC @SQL
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @TEMP WHERE ISLN = @ISLN)
SELECT 1
ELSE 
SELECT 0
```

Dynamic SQL is generated by other software, so I cannot change the input data.

Is there a better way to find specific value in specific column of a dynamic query?

Comment: `sp_sqlexec()` ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, hope it will help you:

```
DECLARE 
  @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
, @ISLN NUMERIC(9,0) = '967272'
SET @SQL = 
'SELECT * 
FROM ITEM 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SHIPMENT_DETAIL 
ON ITEM.ITEM = SHIPMENT_DETAIL.ITEM 
AND (SHIPMENT_DETAIL.COMPANY = ITEM.COMPANY OR ITEM.COMPANY IS NULL)  
WHERE (SHIPMENT_DETAIL.warehouse = N''SH'' ) 
ORDER BY ITEM.ITEM  ASC'

SELECT @SQL = 'if exists (' + STUFF (
    @SQL
    , charindex('where', @sql) + 6
    , 0
    , 'INTERNAL_SHIPMENT_LINE_NUM = ' + cast(@isln as varchar(20)) + ' and '
) + ') select 1 else select 0;';
EXEC SP_SQLEXEC @SQL;
```